# remove gap between buttons in navigation item rightbuttonitems

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems` to setup my navigation bar items. However, for the bar buttons, i'm using a custom view(button). I observe there is spacing between buttons. How can I remove this?

Comment: Can you post a larger block of code, where you're actually setting the value of `rightBarButtonItems`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove it. You can work around it by creating a bar button item with a custom view, where that custom view has you custom buttons all added as subviews. In this way you can directly control the exact positioning.

Comment: Is it possible to just mess with the `contentEdgeInsets` properties of the buttons, as mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3693957/88111

Comment: @CraigOtis it's possible that you could make it work but you're relying on Apple not choosing to change the spacing that they add (and the value of which you guessed).

Comment: That's a good point. Creating your own view containing the buttons, as you describe, is probably a more robust solution.

Answer (score 13):

i know its too late, but i solved it using following method of `UIBarButtonItem`
use

```
[barbuttonitem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -30, 0, -70)];
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using storybord interface.I know you are  using custom Bar,but this answer will useful for those who use stroybord.

1.Select the `Bar item`.

2.Select the `Size Inspector`.

Here you can find image Inset,using `top`,`bottom`  AND `left` , `right` you can change the position of Bar Item.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that how you can resolve this issue:

Create an extension of UIBarButton

```
extension UIBarButtonItem
{
    /** Create custom right bar button for reduce space between right bar buttons */ 
    func initRightButton(let imageNamed:String, let target:UIViewController, let selector:Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {  
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        //Create imageView
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame:frame)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNamed)
        //Create Button
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        button.addTarget(target, action: selector, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        //Create View and add imageView and Button
        let view = UIView(frame: frame)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(button)
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
    }
}
```

In your class controller use the method customizeNavigationBar

```
func customizeNavigationBar()  {
    //Create custom right bar button chat for reduce space between right bar buttons
    let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem().initRightButton("customImageNamed1", target: self, selector: customSelector)
    let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem().initRightButton("customImageNamed2", target: self, selector: customSelector)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barButton1,barButton2]
}
```